# Not able to execute javac and jps

Tags: java, java-8

I have installed java-se-8u41-ri.

I have set JAVA_HOME as environment variable with path /usr/lib/jvm/java-se-8u41-ri/

> I am getting output for java -version as below
>
> openjdk version "1.8.0_41" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_41-b04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

But when I execute jps or javac -version, I get below error

```
javac: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
jps: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/688400/java-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli-so

Comment: You need a JDK (Java Developer Kit), you installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Reinstall Java 8 JDK. Also, "1.8.0_41" is **ancient**.

Comment: If it's for your own, personal use, you can install Oracle's JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)